# Entity framework code generation tool

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, subsonic, scaffold

I have used Subsonic ORM in ASP.NET. It has Scaffold user control that generates web forms for list/insert/edit/delete etc.

I want to know is there anything like this in ASP.NET Entity Framework?

Comment: What do you mean by _forms_? Web Forms, Win Forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [ASP.Net Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata). Its quite nice and provides good scaffolding support.